# how to fix firefox problems creating a bot with instapy that follows other people followers on ig

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, instapy

I was searching for someone to solve this issue but no one knows anything if you know how to fix it pls tell me.
I was working on auto follow other people bot and I know nothing about selenium and instapy so if you can help I appreciate it.
I tried uninstall and reinstall some thing and nothing worked.

`TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firefox_profile'`

full bot code:

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run
from selenium import webdriver

my_username = ''
my_pass = ''

session = InstaPy(username = my_username, password = my_pass, headless_browser = False)


with smart_run(session):
    session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled = True,
                                    delimit_by_numbers=True,
                                    max_followers= 5000,
                                    min_followers= 20,
                                    min_following= 30, )
    session.follow_user_followers(['baker._.305'], amount= 10, randomize= False)
    session.end()
```

Comment: What is your code ? At what line does the problem occur ? What is the complete stacktrace ? A mechanic cannot fix your car if you do not give him your car...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], instructions how to run it and what output you observed. Concerning the exception, include the full backtrace. Also, [edit] your question to fix the applied tags, one of the Python tags must be wrong. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].